# AS3 - Right alignment in DataGrid not working as I expected

Tags: actionscript-3, datagrid, alignment, right-align

Right, so I have a `DataGrid` with two columns. In the left column, I want the text to be aligned to the right: more specifically, if the column is too small to show the entire text, I want it to contain the right-most contents.

I managed to align it by making a custom class extending `CellRenderer` and setting the `DataGrid`'s `cellRenderer` property to the class, as specified in [this article](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/quickstart/datagrid_pt3.html). However, this doesn't work exactly how I want it to. It does indeed align the text to the right, but if the column is too small for all the text to fit, it still only shows the left-most section of it.

Does anybody know how I can make it show the right-most part of the text instead?

Just so you know, this is in a pure AS3 AIR application in FlashDevelop, and my `CellRenderer` class is the same as the one in the article I linked to above (i.e. `RightAlignCell`).

Comment: Did you try changing the `x` property of the `textField`?

Comment: Just to be clear it's working  as expected. Right align doesn't mean "show the right most contents".

Comment: @Gio: Yes, unfortunately that didn't appear to have any effect.
@SunilD: I guess your right, but what I meant was it isn't working how I expected. In programs like Excel, right alignment does this, so I assumed it'd be the same for Flash's `DataGrid`. Anyway fixed the title to reflect that.

Comment: I'm not at my computer ATM, when I get there I'll give it a shot. I think setting the right alignment and setting the `x` property of textField to `this.width - textField.width` will do what you want.

Comment: @Gio: It isn't working for me, but feel free to give it a try. If it works there must be something weird with my code. EDIT: Aha, found the problem. It appears that the `textField`'s width changes to fit inside the column, which means that finding the difference between the two results in +5. I removed `super.drawLayout()` from the overwritten `drawLayout` function in my `CellRenderer`, and it appears to remove the specific problem, but many, many more appear.

Comment: OK, I've found a solution, so I'm going to answer my question. This is the second time in a row it's happened: I have a question, nobody has an answer, but after discussing it in the comments I find my own solution. Thanks a lot guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here was my original code of my `CellRenderer`:

```
package  
{
    import fl.controls.listClasses.CellRenderer;
    import fl.controls.listClasses.ICellRenderer;
    import flash.text.TextFormat;
    import flash.text.TextFormatAlign;

    public class RightAlignCell extends CellRenderer implements ICellRenderer
    {
        private var tf:TextFormat;

        public function RightAlignCell() 
        {
            tf = new TextFormat();
            tf.align = TextFormatAlign.RIGHT;
        }

        override protected function drawLayout():void
        {
            textField.setTextFormat(tf);
            super.drawLayout();
        }

    }

}
```

However, changing the value of `textField.x` had no effect. I figured this was because I was calling `super.drawLayout()` at the end of my overridden version, which apparently changed the value back to the default. If I called it at the start, changing the `x` worked (I'm using -50 here as a noticeable example):

```
        override protected function drawLayout():void
        {
            super.drawLayout();
            textField.setTextFormat(tf);
            textField.x = -50;
        }
```

However, if I tried to set the value to `this.width - textField.width`, as Gio suggested should give the desired result, it only increased the `x` by 5 pixels.
I discovered that the problem was, again, `super.drawLayout()`. It appears that it was resizing the `textField`'s width to fit inside the column, which is why my calculation didn't work. I tried to remove it the function, but that was a big mess since it handled a lot of code necessary for the column to display properly. So instead, I figured to make the `textField` resize itself automatically to its proper width, even when `super.drawLayout()` resized it, using the `autoSize` property:

```
        override protected function drawLayout():void
        {
            super.drawLayout();
            textField.setTextFormat(tf);
            textField.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;
            textField.x = this.width - textField.width;
        }
```

Now it worked, although with a few hitches. These were minimal though, and were fixed by moving the lines defining text format and autosize to the constructor of the `CellRenderer` (which I realised I should have done in the first place anyway). In the end, my final, functional class was this:

```
package  
{
    import fl.controls.listClasses.CellRenderer;
    import fl.controls.listClasses.ICellRenderer;
    import flash.text.TextFormat;
    import flash.text.TextFormatAlign;
    import flash.text.TextFieldAutoSize;

    public class RightAlignCell extends CellRenderer implements ICellRenderer
    {
        private var tf:TextFormat;

        public function RightAlignCell() 
        {
            tf = new TextFormat();
            tf.align = TextFormatAlign.RIGHT;
            textField.setTextFormat(tf);
            textField.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;
        }

        override protected function drawLayout():void
        {
            super.drawLayout();
            textField.x = this.width - textField.width - 5;
        }

    }

}
```

The subtraction of 5 pixels to `textField.x` is just a bit of positioning I did to make the text look better, instead of touching the border of the column.

Sorry for such a long post while the solution is simple, but I decided to explain it in-depth. Basically I just came up with the class above, which worked.

Comment: if you set `autoSize` to `TextFieldAutoSize.RIGHT` you don't need to `setTextFormat`